# Android JSON parsing - Read data from a MySQL db , parsing & display result in a ListView

Tags: android, mysql, json, listview

I'm following a tutorial about `Android JSON parsing` on youtube. I want to read data from `MySQL db` parse into `JSON format` and display them in a list view in my Android app.

I have a created a `PHP` to `decode JSON data` and it shows in my Android app. But when I try to display them in a List View app shows a `blank screen`.

This is my Main Activiy class.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
String json_string;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void getJSON(View view){
    new AsyncTaskRunner().execute();
}

class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    String JSON_STRING;
    String json_url;
    TextView textView;


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        TextView textView= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(result);
        json_string=result;

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(json_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

            InputStream inputStream=httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            StringBuilder stringBuilder =new StringBuilder();

            while((JSON_STRING=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                stringBuilder.append(JSON_STRING+"\n");
            }

            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();

            return stringBuilder.toString().trim();

        }catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        json_url="http://10.0.2.2/ahala_new/json_get_data.php";
    }


    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}

public void parseJSON(View view)
{
    if(json_string==null){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"First get JSON Data",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else{
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,ListView_Display.class);
        intent.putExtra("json_data",json_string);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}}
```

Display List View class

```
public class ListView_Display extends Activity {
String json_string;
JSONObject jsonObject;
JSONArray jsonArray;
PromoAdapter promoAdapter;
ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.display_listview_layout);

    listView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setAdapter(promoAdapter);

    promoAdapter =new PromoAdapter(this,R.layout.row_layout);
    json_string =getIntent().getExtras().getString("json_data");

    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(json_string);
        jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");
        int count=0;
        String name,description,price;
        while (count<jsonObject.length()){

            JSONObject SA=jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
            name=SA.getString("name");
            description=SA.getString("description");
            price=SA.getString("price");

            Promotions promotions=new Promotions(name,description,price);
            promoAdapter.add(promotions);
            count++;

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}}
```

Custom List View Adapter class

```
public class PromoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{
List list=new ArrayList();
public PromoAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
    super(context, resource);
}


public void add(Promotions object){
    super.add(object);
    list.add(object);
}

@Override
public int getCount(){
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position){
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent){
    View row;
    row=convertView;
    PromotionHolder promotionHolder;
    if(row==null){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater= (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout,parent,false);

        promotionHolder = new PromotionHolder();
        promotionHolder.txName=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txName);
        promotionHolder.txDesc=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txDesc);
        promotionHolder.txPrice=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txPrice);

        row.setTag(promotionHolder);

    }

    else{
        promotionHolder= (PromotionHolder) row.getTag();
    }
    Promotions promotions=(Promotions)this.getItem(position);
    promotionHolder.txName.setText(promotions.getName());
    promotionHolder.txDesc.setText(promotions.getDescription());
    promotionHolder.txPrice.setText(promotions.getPrice());

    return row;
}

static class PromotionHolder{
    TextView txName,txDesc,txPrice;

}

}
```

Please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getJSON();
}
public void getJSON(){
    new AsyncTaskRunner().execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi for easier parsing use GSON library it makes your code readable and maintainable

you can refer to this link for more information about this library

https://github.com/google/gson

example implementation of using this library
https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html

Comment: Thank you. I'll check those links.

Answer (score 0):

In `onCreate` method of `ListView_Display` you have this cycle

```
while (count<jsonObject.length()) {

    JSONObject SA=jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
    name=SA.getString("name");
    description=SA.getString("description");
    price=SA.getString("price");

    Promotions promotions=new Promotions(name,description,price);
    promoAdapter.add(promotions);
    count++;

}
```

Didn't you mean to iterate through `jsonArray` instead? Like this:

```
while (count<jsonArray.length()) {

    JSONObject SA=jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
    name=SA.getString("name");
    description=SA.getString("description");
    price=SA.getString("price");

    Promotions promotions=new Promotions(name,description,price);
    promoAdapter.add(promotions);
    count++;

}
```

Not sure it's going to solve your issue though.